# How to avoid escaping & while escaping " with \&quot;

Tags: java, xml, dom, domdocument, createtextnode

As a special requirement, I have been trying to escape `"` with `\&quot;` while writing `XML` using `DOM`.

Unfortunately, when I write text with `Document.createTextNode(TextValue)`, it outputs `\&amp;quot;`. However, the expected is `\&quot;`

Details:

Writing Text Value:

```
    public static boolean setDOMElementValue(Document doc, Element elem, String nodeValue) {
    try {
        elem.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nodeValue));
        return true;
    } catch (DOMException ex) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Writing XML:

```
    public static boolean writeDOMToXML(Document doc, String xmlFilePath) {
    try {
        doc.setXmlStandalone(true);
        // write content into xml file

        // Creating TransformerFactory and Transformer
        Transformer tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        // Setting Transformer's output properties
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        tr.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "no");

        // Setting DOMSource and StreamResult
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        File file = new File(xmlFilePath);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)));

        // Transform and Return
        tr.transform(source, result);
        return true;
    } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError | TransformerConfigurationException ex) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.toString());

        return false;
    } catch (TransformerException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Comment: You can force the `Transformer` not to escape _anything_ using [`transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "text")`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3029456/2071828). That would, however, mean that you would need to escape required characters manually...

Comment: @Boris the Spider This way sounds good, although, this would only create a text file structure. Can't help in this case.

Comment: _escape `"` with `\&quot;`_: What's the use of it? Sounds like you want to transform into HTML, not XML.

Comment: Yes that's HTML, but it is a node text value in XML. Which is supposed to be read as it is later and convert to HTML

Comment: Sounds you want to mix HTML and XML. You can transform directly into HTML: `setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD,"html")`

Comment: @MichaelKonietzka: Yes correct, although, I can't write this file as HTML. Primarily it is an XML and only a few of the nodes have this value with HTML in that.
I was able to do this pretty easily using C#, .NET, `XMLWriter`

Comment: @Indigo any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

When you build a text node with the DOM, you should simply put in any string in there literally e.g. `doc.createTextNode("\"")`. When you serialize the DOM tree the serializer will take care of escaping any character as needed (but within a text node there is no need to escape a double or single quote, that is only necessary inside an attribute value, depending on the attribute value delimiter).

Comment: I think that's understood, the OP says _As a special requirement_. The question is how do you _force_ the transformer to escape quotes in text nodes?

Comment: I see, well, I don't think an XSLT 1.0 transformer can be forced to do that. With XSLT 2.0 like Saxon you would need to use the identity transformation with a character map that maps the quote character as needed.

Comment: @Martin Honnen, yes, what Boris the Spider said is correct. This quote escaping is a special requirement. Normally DOM serializer would take care of the standard escapes but this is an exception.

Comment: I would prefer to stick to the current code structure that I have, since it will have to be changed extensively for this.